# Select two different HTML element types with the same id in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have two different elements with the same `id`. How do I select the `div` element with `id="abc"` in jQuery.

For example:

```
<select id="abc">

  <option>jhon</option>

  <option>Richard</option>

</select>

<div id="abc">

</div>
```

Comment: NO! You CANNOT have the same `id` multiple times on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is given, that you cannot have multiple identic `ID` on same page.

The page won't be (X)HTML Valid **DOM Document**

If you do it, then you can't find elements by their id using javascript call `getElementById(String)`

See references:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.id
- http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqmultiIDs.htm
- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp

---

For targeting multiple `DIV` elements on page, use `.class` instead

```
<select class="abc">
    <option>jhon</option>
    <option>Richard</option>
</select>
<div class="abc">

</div>
```

and find them by jQuery library

```
var divCollection = $(".abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

You CAN have multiple id's you should try to select it with the type of element you want `$('select#abc')` or `$('div#abc')`. You should never do it but its possible. I mean the word IDENTIFIER says it all or ;-) ?

Comment: You COULD have duplicate IDs, however you never, ever should. It is an extremely bad habit to get into and it shatters standards and rules. See @Marek Sebera's answer for references.

Comment: YEAH that's what I said, YOU SHOULD NEVER EVER DO IT !! But it is possible

Answer (score 0):

When you try to just use javascript or jquery only the first id that is first select element will be taken and not the second one.